# Jackson annotations, REST and json array parsing

Tags: android, json, jackson

I have to finish project of another programmer, where he started with Jackson annotations and REST apis. I have no experience with it, and struggling for hours for now. I need to parse json array like this:

```
{
...
"id_s": "3011",
"no_s": "Suteki",
"fl": [
         {
             "v": "1",
             "m": "0",
         "id_fs": "243",
           "f_c": "2013-08-09 14:43:54",
          id_tf": "3",
           "u_c": "Aaa",
           _u_c": "1347678779",
             "c": "Carlos Rojas",
           "c_c": "1" 
          }
      ]
}
```

Existing class is like:

```
@EBean
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Item implements Serializable, MapMarker {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonProperty("id_s")
protected int id;

@JsonProperty("id_sucursal")
public void setId_sucursal(int id_sucursal) {
    this.id = id_sucursal;
}

@JsonProperty("id_fb")
protected String idFacebook;

@JsonProperty("no_s")
private String name;

...
}
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913478/nested-json-parsing-for-android-with-jackson) how to parse array, but how do I get **jsonResponseString** using Jackson annotations? What do I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual problem? You are showing JSON, and suggested object, but how does it not work? What do you mean by `jsonResponseString`? Why would you want JSON as a String, instead of getting directly written as a response or read from request? What framework are you using (if any)? I assume it is for client-side (since it's for Android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from missing lots of things that would help answer your question, I am guessing that you are not sure how JSON Arrays would map to Java objects. If so, it should be straight-forward: you map JSON Arrays as either Java arrays, or `Collection`s (like `List`s):

```
public class Item { // i'll skip getters/setters; can add if you like them
  public String id_s;
  public String no_s;

  public List<Entry> fl;
}

public class Entry {
  public String v; // or maybe it's supposed to be 'int'? Can use that
  public String m;
  public int id_fs; // odd that it's a String in JSON; but can convert
  public String f_c; // could be java.util.Date, but Format non-standard (fixable)
  // and so on.
}
```

and you either read JSON as objects:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Item requestedItem = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Item.class); // or from String, URL etc
// or, write to a stream
OutputStream out = ...;
Item result = ...;
mapper.writeValue(out, result);
// or convert to a String
String jsonAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
// note, however, that converting to String, then outputting is less efficient
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it before, but it seems like this here helped another user: [How can I serialize this JSON using Jackson annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410470/how-can-i-serialize-this-json-using-jackson-annotations)

Also, if you can, why don't you just use Android default JSON classes? Googled a random tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry, info from your link is irrelevant, I need parse json array, not simply object..

Comment: Google's default library does not do data-binding, and I don't think it should be used for anything other than casual json handling.