# Jackson annotations tutorials?

Tags: android, jackson

Does somebody aware of some good jackson annotations tutorials? Especially, how do you parse json array using jackson annotations?
 Suppose I have json like this:

```
{
...
"item1": "aaa",
"item2": "bbb",
"fl": [
     {
         "item3": "ccc",
         "item4": "ddd"
      }
  ]
}
```

How does one parse json including array using jackson annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking about how to map JSON into Java objects (parsing typically refers to lower level activity of decoding JSON content stream into another representation, which may or may not be set of objects).

With Jackson (as well as many other libs, Genson, GSON etc), you have choice of either binding it into a POJO with matching structure, say:

```
public class Value { 
  public String item1; // or some other type one can bind from JSON String
  public String item2; // can alternatively use getters/setters instead of public fields
  public List<EntryType> f1;
}
public class EntryType {
  public String item3;
  public String item4;
}
```

or reading it as a Tree representation like so:

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(inputSource);
```

In latter case, you need to traverse the tree nodes to find your data.

As to annotations: you only need to use annotations if you need to change default properties of binding; like mapping between JSON Object fields and POJO property names.

For Jackson-specific configuration including some of annotations, see Jackson-databind github project: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/

Comment: I see.. could you please take a look at my other question related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261592/jackson-annotations-rest-and-json-array-parsing

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to parse json using Jackson -

1. Using a streaming Parser. (http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-json-streaming.jsp)
2. Parsing Json to a tree model - http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-json-tree-parsing.jsp
3. Data binding with our without annotations - [data binding](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Data-Binding.jsp), [data binding with filters](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-data-binding-filters.jsp), [Polymorphic data binding](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-polymorphism.jsp)